# Ninja framework Install Error with Maven

Tags: java, maven, ninjaframework

I'm trying to learn Ninja framework for building RESTful web services at [**here**](http://www.ninjaframework.org/documentation/getting_started/create_your_first_application.html)

I got the following error when I run "mvn clean install" inside the newly created maven project folder:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.610 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-05-19T11:39:50-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project ninja: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.7 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I am on Mac Mavericks with Java 8, if this matters. Thanks

Comment: Why man? Why are you trying to learn restfull webservices through ninja framework? spring or jersey is not enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, it may sound silly, but I fixed the problem by adding JAVA_HOME to the path on my Mac, otherwise, maven still uses Java 1.6 (I've installed Java 1.8) on my computer.

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```